# C++ function-parameter default usage

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I am trying to understand parameter defaulting and I have this code passing 3 arguments to a function and returns the product.

How can I make the code on the `cout<<"3---...`  and "4---" lines below to use the default values from the parameters? See my output at the bottom

CODE

```
            #include "stdafx.h"
            #include<iostream>

            using namespace std;

            int product(char str,int a=5, int b=2);

            int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
            {



                cout<<"1---"<<product('A',40,50)<<endl;

                cout<<"2---"<<product('A')<<endl;
                cout<<"3---"<<product('A',NULL,50)<<endl;
                cout<<"4---"<<product('A',40)<<endl;

                int retValue=product('A',40,50);
                cout<<"5---"<<retValue<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;
            }


            int product(char str,int a, int b){

                return(a*b);
            }
```

## OUTPUT

1---2000

2---10

3---0

4---80

5---2000

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Is the shouting really necessary? The title stands out well enough as is.

Comment: I don't get what's wrong with 4, but 3 isn't possible unless you write another function or use something like Boost's named parameters.

Comment: @chris how did I do it? shout? I just typed OUTPUT the same way I typed CODE. Blame it on the "blackbox" transformation.

Thanks anyway

Comment: That's not what I was referring to. I was referring to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that in case 4 you want the value `40` to be the third argument. There's no way of doing it with function default arguments, the order is what it is defined to be. You can however *override* the function, to create a two-argument version that calls the three-argument function with the correct "default" argument:

```
int product(char str, int a, int b)
{
    ...
}

int product(char str, int b = 2)
{
    return product(str, 5, b);
}
```

With the above functions, calling with one or two arguments, you call the last function, but if you call it with three arguments you call the first one.

Unfortunately there is no way now of calling with `a` set but with `b` set to its default with the above. Instead you have use different named functions for it, or to add dummy arguments or to check e.g. for special value for arguments, or you have to resort to "hacks" like the [Boost parameter library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) (as suggested by chris).

Answer (score 0):

Relevant code:

```
int product(char str,int a=5, int b=2) { return a*b; }

    cout<<"3---"<<product('A',0,50);   // NULL stripped, it's for pointers
    cout<<"4---"<<product('A',40);
```

Given desired output:

```
3---0
4---80
```

If the sample output for #3 is correct, using the default for `a` you'd get 250 not zero.  Is your sample output wrong, then?

```
$ cat t.cpp
#include <iostream>
int product(char c, int a=5, int b=2) { return a*b; }
int main (int c, char **v)
{
    std::cout<<"3---"<<product('A',0,50)<<'\n';
    std::cout<<"4---"<<product('A',40)<<'\n';
}
$ make
g++ -o bin/t -g -O   --std=gnu++11 -march=native -pipe -Wall -Wno-parentheses  t.cpp
$ .bin/t
bash: .bin/t: No such file or directory
$ bin/t
3---0
4---80
$
```